# Amazon aws s3 client error aws-sdk ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

initializer/aws.rb

```
  keys = Rails.application.credentials[:aws]

creds = Aws::Credentials.new(keys[:access_key_id], keys[:secret_access_key])

Aws.config.update({
  service: "s3",
  region: 'eu-west-2',
  credentials: creds
})
```

when i do in my controller this i get error

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(
  region: Aws.config[:region],
  credentials: Aws.config[:credentials]
)

#ArgumentError (invalid configuration option `:service'):
```

I use IAM credentials 
`ruby-sdk-3`

ok I deleted `service` from `Aws.config` and it works but it would be nice to store this param in config

Answer (score 0):

```
s3 = Aws::Client.new(
  region: Aws.config[:region],
  credentials: Aws.config[:credentials]
)
```

try with this!!

[AWS Ruby-sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/index.html)

I hope this will help you!

Comment: @hodiecode, look this (the comments), maybe it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914089/aws-sdk-rails-uninitialized-constant-awss3-nameerror?noredirect=1#comment88853837_50914089

Comment: @iGian the post you poiting is in `ruby-sdk-2`(which is mine topic also lol), here I want to use `ruby-sdk-3`. It works now but I cant keep 'service' in config